# Can't parse DOM from Google.Images, but can from any other Webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, html-parsing

I am trying to parse the DOM from a Google.images page and the response is empty, while when i am trying to parse the DOM from another webpage my code works.

I have used a script so i can make Cross-domain requests with jQuery (**[link](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/)** and **[code](https://raw.github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js)**).

I have used this code:

```
//var url="https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?&image_url=http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/spacecraft/images/spacecraft.jpg";
var url="http://stackoverflow.com/";
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,   
    type: "get",
    dataType: "",
    success: function (data) {
      $('#body').append(data.responseText);
      if(data.responseText===""){$('#body').append("empty response text");}
    },
    error: function (status) {
      console.log("request error:"+url);
    }
  });
});
```

While this code works for any external webpage (e.g. `var url="http://stackoverflow.com/";`)

it doesn't work for Google.images(e.g. `var url="https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?&image_url=http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/spacecraft/images/spacecraft.jpg";`)

So my question is how can i parse the DOM from the Google.images page?

I don't mind using any other library

And a fiddle to play around: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/12asgt79/)**